# How to parse an ini-file containing special characters with "parse_ini_file"?

Tags: php, parsing, character-encoding, ini

I have a folder.ini containing:

```
[Labels]
; Ordnername
name=testverzeichnis
; Ordnerbeschreibung
description=verzeichnis zu testen von daten
[Contents]
[Publisher]
publisher=e-Solutions
copyright=André Reinhardt
```

and when I parse it with `parse_ini_file()` I got `�` instead of `é`.
My Code:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sad - Kopie (6)/folder.ini", TRUE);
print_r($ini_array);
```

I tried to replace `é` with `&eacute;` but then my string is `0`.

**Addition:**
This code to view the content **works** with both, `é` and `&eacute`:

```
echo file_get_contents($directories[$i]."/folder.ini")
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Show some code. How and where are you outputting the data?

Comment: You will likely output the `é` as UTF-8 which does not work. Check the encoding the ini file is saved as.

Comment: It's more likely the other way round - the INI file being stored as ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252, and UTF-8 being used as the output encoding

Comment: Make sure file is saved in UTF8 and without BOM

Comment: @Pekka: That is *"output as UTF-8"*.

Comment: I can not influence how the file is encoded because it´s imported from outside

Comment: @Paedow then there's iconv(): http://php.net/iconv

Comment: @Paedow: Then you need to find out/tell a) in which encoding it is (ask the creator of the file) and b) what the output encoding of your PHP script is. If you add these two technical details, then it is possible to safely deal with this regardless which encoding the file is.

Comment: see [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: and how do I do this? 1. I usually don´t handle this much with encodings and this stuff and 2. I´m new to PHP

Comment: @Paedow: I added an example in my answer. This assumes you use the ISO-8859-1 encoding in the ini and UTF-8 for your PHP scripts output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is an assumption because your question does not document technically so far what the actual cause is.

However what can be said is that you have a character encoding related issue here.

Save your INI file with the UTF-8 encoding and this *should* work. I assume your PHP script outputs UTF-8 to the browser and the values in the INI file are not UTF-8 encoded. If you save the INI file with UTF-8 encoding, this *should* then work.

The key point here is not so much the "UTF-8" but that you save the INI file with the right character encoding that is expected from the application you use. For example if your application uses ISO-8859-1, then save the INI file with the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Both - the INI file and the PHP script - need to speak the same "language".

You can add a "translator" that is able to help you bring two different "languages" together. Such a translator (or more correctly *re-encoder*) is [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv):

```
$ini_iso88591 = file_get_contents("sad - Kopie (6)/folder.ini");
$ini_utf8     = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $ini_iso88591);
$ini_array    = parse_ini_string($ini_utf8, TRUE);
```